# How To Include Header Information in ToJSON Output

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, json.net

Hi there I have a requirement to provide a JSON array for delivery to one of our clients. The JSON is based on the following 'Model' components:

```
 Public Class PIValues
     Inherits List(Of PIValue)

     Public Sub New()
     End Sub
 End Class

 Public Class PIValue
     Private _PointName As String
     Private _value As Double
     Public Property PointName() As String
         Get
             PointName = _PointName
         End Get
         Set(value As String)
             _PointName = value
         End Set
     End Property
     Public Property Value() As Double
         Get
             Value = _value
         End Get
         Set(value As Double)
             _value = value
         End Set
     End Property
 End Class
```

Its a breeze to generate the required JSON output however I also need to provide some header information as part of the package in the form:

```
 TimeStamp: <yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss>
```

Where the contents within the chevrons are a variable time stamp of the specified format.

How can I insert this information into the JSON package?

Kind Regards
Paul.

Comment: Add a TimeStamp property to your PIValues class. Then set it's value before exporting to JSON

Comment: `PIValues` is a collection so will be serialized to JSON as an array of values, specifically an array of serialized `PIValue` objects.  Where do you want the `"TimeStamp" : "<yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss>"` to appear?

Comment: Where is your JSON package?  What is your expected json string?

Comment: Guys, the customer wants the timetamp as a single entry in the file rather than as part of the collection.  The data content will be quite large hence the requirement for not having repeating infomation in the core data.  Ideally the TimeStamp would be a singe line at the head of the package.  Unfortunately the data content is confidential so unable to post on here.

Comment: @PaulJohnson - we're not asking to post "real" data.  We just want to see your desired JSON output with fake data.  I.e. "foo" for `PointName` and `1.0` for `Value`.  But from your comment it sounds like your client doesn't want JSON at all, they want text that includes some JSON.  In order to do that, we need to know how you are generating your output; your title mentions `ToJSON` but where are you calling that?